# Excel vba: MsgBox gets shows up too early

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` sub that selects a `sheet2` and displays a message if a cell from column 3 is selected:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 3 Then
    Dim response As VbMsgBoxResult

    Select Case Target.Row
      Case 5:
        Sheets("sheet2").Select
        MsgBox ("Test") 'this msgbox shows up early
        'response = MsgBox("Question here?", vbYesNo, "Question title") 'this msgbox shows up early too

    End Select
  End If

End Sub
```

However the message gets displayed too early - while the `sheet1` is still active. How would I fix it?

For `sheet2` to get displayed I need to first close a `MsgBox` window, which is inconvenient because the window content is connected to `sheet2` content.

**EDIT**: I think I figured it out. I had a `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` in my code. No it all works. Thanks!

Comment: Does Sheet2 display *after* the message gets displayed?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  My sheet2 shows  before the msgbox shows.

Comment: put a DoEvents between the worksheet select and the msgbox.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad yes, please, see edit.

Comment: @Jeeped Still the same, unfortunatelly...

Comment: I placed you code in sheet1 module, when I clicked C5, it selected sheet2 and then the msgbox popped up. I would assume your code has selected sheet2, but just doesn't show on the screen until you click the OK on the msgbox. Maybe change the msgbox to `MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name` and see what the msg comes up as.

Comment: @Davesexcel I think I figured it out. I had a `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` in my code. No it all works. Thanks!

Comment: You could either place that as an answer or delete the post. BTW your original post did not have application.screenupdating in the code, somebody would hve noticed it right away.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, for example:

First, modify your Sheet1 code as displayed here.

```
'// In Sheet1
Public bShowMessageBox As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'//-- Your code here
    Select Case Target.Row
      Case 5:
        Sheets("sheet2").Select
        bShowMessageBox = True
'''        MsgBox ("Test") 'this msgbox shows up early
'''        'response = MsgBox("Question here?", vbYesNo, "Question title") 'this msgbox shows up early too
    End Select
'//-- Your code here
End Sub

Public Sub ShowMessageBox()
    bShowMessageBox = False
    MsgBox ("Test") 'this msgbox shows up early
    'response = MsgBox("Question here?", vbYesNo, "Question title") 'this msgbox shows up early too
End Sub
```

Second, add some code to the Sheet2.

```
'// In Sheet2
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If Sheet1.bShowMessageBox Then
        Call Sheet1.ShowMessageBox
    End If
End Sub
```